# Windows Server 2012 Drives Not Mapping After ISP Change

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, mappeddrive

Im new to setting up servers, Ive been reading my guide books but recently I ran into a problem that I can not solve. I work for a company with a small network  and they decided to change the ISP provider. Now the network drives will not map on the client machines using the script I created in the GP. Im running windows server 2012 as a DC, Im installed AD DS, DHCP, DNS, and File and Storage Services all on this one DC.
These are the error messages I am receiving on the servers dashboard

AD DS Errors

- 10020 Warning Microsoft-Windows-DHCP-Server
- 2089 Warning Microsoft-Windows-ActiveDirectory_DomainService
- 2213 Warning DFSR DFS Replication
- 1400 Error ADWS Active Directory Web Services
- 2886 Warning Microsoft-Windows-ActiveDirectory_DomainService
- 4013 Warning Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Server-Service
- 1202 Error ADWS Active Directory web service

DCHP Errors

- 10020 Warning Microsoft-Windows-DHCP-Server
- 1059 Error Microsoft-Windows-DHCP-Server

DNS Errors

- 4013 Warning Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Server-Service

I tried to change the ip address in DHCP management and that didn't work I also tried to change the DNS settings.

Comment: Run an ipconfig /all on a computer in problem, often new modem cable got a integrated router and will put down your network. If so, call your isp, they can remotly disable it usually

Comment: What DNS server(s) are your domain clients using for DNS? This sounds like an incorrect DNS configuration problem.

Comment: Your internal AD communication and network communication shouldn't be affected by an ISP change, which leads me to believe that you're using your router for DHCP and DNS or you're using your ISP for DNS, neither of which you should be doing.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds to me like you may have changed the DNS settings on the server and it cannot communicate with Active Directory. Set the Primary DNS server on the servers NIC to 127.0.0.1 (the loopback address - the sever itself) and leave the secondary blank as in the following image:

[DNS settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwzT7.png)

In DHCP management, under Scope options ensure that the DNS Server is set to the internal IP of the server, and router is set to the internal IP address of the ISP router. Restart the DNS and then the DHCP services and check for errors in the logs. Hopefully that resolves the internal connectivity issues.

If you then have internet issues you can set the DNS forwarders to the DNs servers provided by the ISP as per https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754941.aspx.

I hope that helps resolve the issues.

Marcus

Comment: In this scenario, 127.0.0.1 should be configured as secondary DNS, not primary DNS. In a single DC environment the DC's "real" ip address should be used as primary DNS. In a multiple DC environment, 127.0.0.1 should be configured as tertiary DNS. This will be specifically called out in the DNS BPA on the DC.